# RTOS for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, rtos

is there any project of an rtos that works on arduino ?

Comment: There are RTOS projects that will run on an *ATMega*, but anything similar is not likely to use the arduino environment.

Comment: I want to inform also that QP the famous state machine framework is now available for arduino http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/QP

Comment: related: [What Operating Systems are available for Arduino?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/what-operating-systems-are-available-for-arduino)

Answer (score 6):

I have been using [FemtoOS](http://femtoos.org/) in few projects and it works very well.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a good summary of the [current offerings](http://www.out--there.com/blog/rtos-for-arduino/) - the favorite looks like [DuinOS](http://robotgroup.com.ar/noticias/20091102/duinos-sistema-operativo-multitarea-para-arduino)

Also consider [Aiko](http://github.com/geekscape/Aiko)

Answer (score 2):

the link to download DuinOS had changed to this:

http://robotgroup.com.ar/duinos/wiki

There you will find (in the downloads section) the v0.1 and the v0.2 versions.

Regards,
Julián
http://robotgroup.com.ar

Comment: Looks like it moved AGAIN and there's no HTTP Redirect on the old site..  It appears the current home (or current active fork) is here:https://github.com/DuinOS/DuinOS

Answer (score 1):

If you need simple multithreading on to of "bare-metal", then I'd recommend [Protothreads](http://www.sics.se/~adam/pt/) which are rather easy to use and
there is very tiny overhead (just a few bytes)!

I haven't tested Protothreads in the Arduino Library context, though this should
work and as I can see [someone already done it](http://arduinocollective.com/2009/12/05/arduino-threading/).

Protothreads are also part of [Contiki OS](http://www.sics.se/~adam/contiki/) which is
an excellent solution for wireless sensor network applications. There had been some effort of porting Contiki to run a few popular Arduino boards.

A git repository of the orginal port can be found [here](https://github.com/zxombie/contiki-arduino/), though I have attempted to
update it more recent version Contiki and it is [here](https://github.com/contiki/contiki-arduino/). This code works as far as some
basic *"Hello World!"* examples are concerned and it will require some extra work to get networking (i.e. 6loWPAN/uIP), though beware that if you don't need networking there no much benefit of using Contiki and if you have an Ethernet Shield, you don't need the networking as such, because that is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at [atomthreads](http://atomthreads.com/). That should run on avr's but I don't know if you can merge any of the fw/sw parts of Arduino into it.