# What is the best Arduino Operating System?

Tags: arduino, os

What is the best Arduino Operating System?

Comment: What do you mean?  The best OS to do Arduino development on, or the best OS to run on your Arduino (a la FreeRTOS)?

Comment: In addition, it might be worthwhile to ask "best for what?"  That is, each OS (arduino or computer) would have different advantages given different problem spaces.  That would be helpful in answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno which one is the best, but I really liked DuinOS when I played with it a while back.

It didn't quite work right out of the box and required some tweaking, but I don't remember it being difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

check out this question
[RTOS for Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/815/rtos-for-arduino)

Answer (score 0):

Look for PrXos at [arduinoprx.de](http://arduinoprx.de).
In March comes the Final !!!!